# Deprecated function mysql_db_query error

Tags: php, mysql, deprecated

Recently after my hosting updated its php version i've got error in my website and here is the error message

```
Deprecated: Function mysql_db_query() is deprecated in /my_path/file.php on line 13 
Deprecated: Function mysql_db_query() is deprecated in /my_path/file.php on line 14
```

Here is the code of the `file.php`

```
require_once("db.php"); // connect
$timeoutseconds = 100;
$timestamp=time();
$timeout=$timestamp-$timeoutseconds;


mysql_db_query($db, "INSERT INTO online VALUES ('$timestamp','$REMOTE_ADDR','$PHP_SELF')") or die("0 Users online"); // this is line 13 that shows error

mysql_db_query($db, "DELETE FROM online WHERE timestamp<$timeout") or die("0 Users online"); // this is line 14 that shows error
```

Is there explain for this error and how can fix it ? ~ thanks

Note : i know about `mysqli` and `pdo` but can't shift to any since my website depends mainly on `mysql` and will needs months to do major changes so please can you stick with `mysql`.

Comment: mysqli_* is basically mysql_* with an i. Edit: With updated/better code, of course.

Comment: you should update your code to use mysqli_ function, if you don't use the OO methods it shouldn't need much changes to the code.

Comment: Stop using deprecated libraries.

Comment: Time to update your site.

Comment: All the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, so you really can't *fix* it. It is possible to *hide* these warnings by changing your PHP configuration but I don't really recommend that. Just **stop using the deprecated functions** and switch to MySQLi or PDO :)

Comment: All-right guys but what about now ! can i just fix this error till i update my website , i know mysqli and pdo are mainly essential more safety more better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upgrade to MySQLi or even better, PDO. However, I understand that you may need a solution as of right now because you have a live website and you want to hide errors (yet the website will still work). But, you will need to consider upgrading because theses functions will be removed in a near future.

Add this to your main file at the top.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

or

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: @DavidBélanger 'E' stands for 'Error'. Nevertheless, do you really want to rely on a feature that will be removed in near future?

Comment: @ComFreek No, of course and I will suggest PDO here, but this ain't the point. You cannot rewrite all the query in 5 seconds if you have a live website so for now you hide the errors, you update your website with PDO and you publish it. Would you keep all the error displayed while you fix them ? Hell no.

Comment: While technically correct, this answer advises bad practices. Hiding warnings/errors/notices is *NEVER* the solution.

Comment: Hiding anything that could potentially be bad is just a giant "no" in programming. Warnings exist for a reason, if you choose to ignore them it would have to be a fairly significant reason for there to not be a better way.

Comment: Not displaying a notice in your live site for an issue you're aware of that requires rewriting the whole codebase? It is actually a sensible idea, isn't it?

Comment: @David Bélanger thank you for helping at least rather than talking about updating you've given me fast solution and advised me to update .. thanks a lot.

Comment: @JackBen No problem, but do not forget to do it ! Really important. This is only a solution for a short term.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `mysql` functions have been deprecated in PHP 5.5.

You can't "fix" this -- it's how things are.

Your options are:

1. **Downgrade back to PHP 5.4.**
   That doesn't sound like an option, given that your webhost did the upgrade.
2. **Just do the work.**
   Honestly, it's not that big a deal to switch from the `mysql_` functions to the `mysqli_` functions. The APIs are very similar; the main difference is that the `i` functions require the connection variable to be passed. But that's hardly an insurmountable problem. Converting to `mysqli` is actually pretty simple if you put your mind to it. It certainly won't take months (unless your code really is a disaster zone where any minor change would take months).
3. **Ignore the warnings.**
   They are only warnings; your program will continue to run despite them, so just set PHP's error handling to ignore deprecation warnings, and they'll disappear. However, don't think this lets you off the hook -- when your webhost upgrades next time and the functions have been completely removed from the language, it will be a lot harder to fix, and a lot more urgent. Seriously, do the work now: you'll save yourself a mountain of pain later.

Comment: When upgrading the code to MySQLi, I strongly suggest to use prepared statements.